# How do I plot p-value of wilcox.test()?

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to compare two algorithms, `f(n)` and `g(n)`, with `wilcox.test()` to show that `f` is better than `g`.

The data frame is as follows:

```
Algorithm 0   20 40 60 ...
f         100 90 80 70 ...
g         110 92 81 71 ...
f         130 100 90 85 ...
g         135 99 95 90 ...
f         ...
g         ...
f         ...
g         ...
...
```

I got p-values for each column(about 40 columns) manually and stored them into an csv and plotted it.

```
> wilcox.test(..., alternative="less", paired=FALSE) for column 0
> wilcox.test(..., alternative="less", paired=FALSE) for column 20
> wilcox.test(..., alternative="less", paired=FALSE) for column 40
> # feels like forever
```

The problem is, I found that I had a mistake implementing the algorithms, so I need to rerun the program and do it again.

How do I get the p-value for each column and plot it? It might be a newbie question and I know it might look like a question without sufficient survey, but I need help seriously. so please help me.

Comment: You may access the p-value via `$p.value`. For example: `mytest <- wilcox.test(1:10, 11:20, alternative="less", paired=FALSE); mytest$p.value`.

Comment: Since the first parameters of `wilcox.test()` expect vectors of observations (as opposed to single values), I think your sample data does not yet provide a good example (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, your "f"-row of the "20"-column now contains just the single number "90", while a vector of inputs might be more demonstrative.

Comment: @texb There's a lot more rows in the file. I though it would be enough to put `...` and i guess it's not. I'll edit the post.

Comment: @kukyakya you need multiple values to do the `wilcox.test` test with. It won't work with one number and one number. Is this count data? Perhaps a `fisher.test` or a `chisq.test` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You need a for loop:

```
results <- numeric(0) # an empty vector 
for (i in 1:ncol(mydata))) {
    results[i] <- wilcox.test(mydata[,i] ~ mydata$algorithm)$p.value
}
```

Untested.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in dat data.frame:

```
Algorithm =rep(c("f","g"),leng=nrow(dat))
Names=unique(Algorithm )
pvals=apply(dat,2,function(co){
sdf=lapply(Names,function(x) co[Names == x])
wilcox.test(sdf[[1]],sdf[[2]], alternative="less", paired=FALSE)$p.value
})

barplot(pvals,names.arg = colnames(dat),col=rainbow(ncol(dat)))
```

[image]